# RxJava retryWhen resubscribe propagation

Tags: java, android, java-8, retrofit, rx-java

I'm using Retrofit with RxJava in an Android app for communications and have to handle error on parsing the response from a seemly ok HTTP response (status 200 code).

I have also implemented a way of handling the error using `retryWhen` operator which is connected to user's input to decide whether to retry it or not. This works by resubscribing to the original `Observable`.

The first approach I have tried was to have something like this:

```
services.getSomething()
  .map(response -> {
    if (checkBadResponse(response)) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error on service");
    } else {
      return parseResponse(response);
    }
  }).retryWhen(this::shouldRetry);
```

With this the service is not called again. It seems the `retryWhen` operator cannot resubscribe to the service's `Observable`.

What end up working was implementing another operator which doesn't send the `onCompleted` forward and use it with `lift` like the following:

```
public class CheckResponseStatus<T> implements Observable.Operator<ResponsePayload<T>, ResponsePayload<T>> {
    @Override
    public Subscriber<? super ResponsePayload<T>> call(Subscriber<? super ResponsePayload<T>> subscriber) {
        return new Subscriber<ResponsePayload<T>>() {
            private boolean hasError = false;

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                if (!hasError)
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                hasError = true;
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(ResponsePayload<T> response) {
                if (response.isOk()) {
                    subscriber.onNext(response);
                } else {
                    hasError = true;
                    subscriber.onError(new RuntimeException(response.getMessage()));
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Using it like:

```
services.getSomething()
  .lift(new CheckResponseStatus())
  .map(response -> parseResponse(response))
  .retryWhen(this::shouldRetry);
```

Is this the correct way of dealing with it or is there a simpler, better way?

Comment: If you remove `.retryWhen`, do you receive `onError` in your Observer?

Comment: Yes, I do! The error is normally propagated.

Comment: `RetryWhen` is a particularly difficult operator to understand because of how you can tell it to resubscribe through the function supplied to it. What I could decipher from its code is that you can't ignore the incoming observable and you have to chain through it.

Comment: I have managed the logic for the `retryWhen` to work as intended with this `shouldRetry` method not shown on the code. The problem is really when I try to generate an error by throwing from the function passed to `map`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's looks like a bug in `rx-java` implementation. Anyway, throwing an exception from `map` function is a bad thing since the function is supposed to be pure (e.g. without side effects). You should use a `flatMap` operator in your case:

```
services.getSomething()
  .flatMap(response -> {
    if (checkBadResponse(response)) {
      return Observable.<ResponseType>error(new RuntimeException("Error on service"));
    } else {
      return Observable.<ResponseType>just(parseResponse(response);
    }
  }).retryWhen(this::shouldRetry);
```

The code above works as expected and really retries the request if error occurs.

Comment: This is indeed a simpler way instead of implementing the operator to use with `lift`. I'll check to see if this works in my scenario. I really didn't think of throwing inside `map` to be a side effect, only a way of triggering the error which is already implemented on RxJava, but that's surely a point. I caught this idea from some other question.

Comment: @AndreLuiz What version of `rxjava` do you use? I've just found this issue on github https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/2852 and it looks like it was fixed in `1.0.9`.

Comment: I was using 1.0.4, included by latest RxAndroid 0.24.0. Just tested with 1.0.10 and it worked! It was indeed a bug. And by the way the version using `flatMap` also works on 1.0.4. Thank you! :)

Comment: I don't think throwing from `map` is a bad idea. In fact, I believe it conveys programmer's intention much more clear than using `flatMap` and piling up artificial `Observables` as you do in your example.